# select A, B , C group by B with A from the row that has the highest C

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have collected informations from different sources about certain IDs that should match a single name. Some sources are more trustworthy than others in giving the correct name for a given ID.

I created a table (name, id, source_trustworthiness) and I want to get the most trustworthy name for each ID.

I tried

```
SELECT name, id, MAX( source_trustworthiness )
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

this returns th highest trustworthiness available for each ID but with the first name it finds, regarless of its trustworthiness.

Is there a way I can get that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql has special functionality to help:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name, id, source_trustworthiness
  FROM table
  ORDER BY 3 DESC ) x
GROUP BY id
```

Although this wouldn't even execute in other databases (not naming all non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause), with mysql it returns the *first* row encountered for each unique value of the grouped by columns. By ordering the rows greatest first, the first row for each id will be the most trustworthy.

Since this question is tagged [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), this query is OK. Not only is it really simple, it's also quite fast.

Comment: In the end I used this query because it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id, MAX(source_trustworthiness) max_val
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.source_trustworthiness = b.max_val
```